# dropzone.js autoprocessqueue:false don't work

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I try to use a button to submit my download. I am following the introduction of [this guide](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Upload-all-files-with-a-button).

This is my path:

```
<form action="index.php/controller/upload" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"></form>
```

and this is my upload function:

```
public function upload() {
        if (!empty($_FILES)) {
            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $fileName = 'test.csv';
            $targetPath = getcwd() . '/application/models/uploads/';
            $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName;
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
        }
    }
```

just standard stuff but what am I missing? Because it is still uploading instantly.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit my dropzone function to your needs

```
var QuoteDropzone = new Dropzone('#quote_upload', {
 init: function () {
    var dropzone = this;
    $("#removeAllFiles").click(function () {
        dropzone.removeAllFiles();
    });

    $('#quote_upload_submit').click(function () {
        QuoteDropzone.processQueue();
    });
},
parallelUploads: 20,
url: "/quotes/quote-upload",
autoProcessQueue: false,
type: 'POST',
success: function () {
    toastr.success('<h3>Success</h3><p>Files Uploaded</p>');
},
error: function() {
    toastr.error('<h3>Error</h3><p>Files Not Uploaded</p>');
}
});
```

will help you more tonight if you still have a problem